# How to "add" not "overwrite" amount using WriteDMAInteger

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program that changes address values however I want to be able to "add" lets say "500" to the current address. Not to  change "1500" to "500". Any ways I can make this happen?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ammount As String = TextBox1.Text
    Try
        WriteDMAInteger("Process.dat", GetModuleHandle("Process.dat", "Process.dat") + &H3B80F8, {&H790}, ammount, 1, 4)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming there is no `AddDMAInteger` method, you will need to read the current value (perhaps with `ReadDMAInteger`), do the addition yourself and then write the result with `WriteDMAInteger`.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps use a integer to mark the output using `ReadDMAInteger`? Because that may just work. `Dim total as integer` `total = ReadDMAInteger("Process.dat", Get....`

Comment: Please show us the `ReadDMAInteger` and `WriteDMAInteger` methods. We have no idea how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @Visual Vincent for recommending or reminding me to use the `"ReadDMAInteger"` method. Using `"ReadDMAInteger"` I'm able to read the value of a address and have that be the value of the integer. From there I can simply use the integer and plug and play.

Of course, you would want to have a timer setup using this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Try
                My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Speech_Sleep, AudioPlayMode.Background)
                Dim ammount As String = TextBox1.Text

                Dim total1 As Integer
                Dim totalstring1 As Integer
                Dim final1 As Integer

                total1 = ReadDMAInteger("Process.dat", GetModuleHandle("Process.dat", "Process.dat") + &H3B80F8, {&H790}, 1)

                totalstring1 = TextBox1.Text.Trim
                final1 = (total1 + totalstring1)

                Try
                    WriteDMAInteger("Process", GetModuleHandle("Process.dat", "Process.dat") + &H3B80F8, {&H790}, final1, 1, 4)
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
```

Comment: Glad you solved it, but wasn't it Blackwood that reminded you of the `ReadDMAInteger` method? I merely asked to see the method's code. :)